# generators that defer to sub-generators

Tags: python

I yould like to have generators that defer to other generators, e.g.

```
def gx():
    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        yield i

def gy():
    for i in [11, 12, 13]:
        yield i

def gz():
    """this should defer to gx and gy to
       generate [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13]"""
    for i in gx(): yield i
    for i in gy(): yield i
```

Is the explicit loop in gz() the only way to do this, or are there better alternatives?

Comment: Do you need to solve an actual problem or are you just interested in knowing if there's a specific feature for that in Python?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In currently released Python versions, an explicit loop is the only way to invoke sub-generators.  (I presume your example is just, well, an example -- not the exact problem you want to solve.)

Python 3.3 will add the special syntax `yield from` for this purpose:

```
def gz():
    """this should defer to gx and gy to
       generate [1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13]"""
    yield from gx()
    yield from gy()
```

See [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) for further details.

Comment: +1 for explaining about the new features that are coming up in 3.3

Comment: Why the down vote?  My gut feeling is that this is the answer the OP is actually after, judging from the title of the question.

Answer (score 11):

Using [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools

gz = itertools.chain(gx(), gy())
```

In the documentation of `chain` they describe it by implementation:

```
def chain(*iterables):
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            yield element
```

You can draw inspiration from this as well :)